# Expressjs - How to prevent a user from posting a registration form...?

Tags: node.js, session, express

Is the following an appropriate way to redirect a user if they are trying to `POST` data to the registration form if they are already logged in or is there a better more secure way? I am preventing them from a `GET` request to the registration form, but I also want to prevent them from making a `POST` request thought other means then a form.

The check is:

```
if(true !== req.session.loggedIn){

}else{

}
```

In the app.js file:

```
app.get('/register',register.registration);
app.post('/register',register.doRegistration);
```

This is the controller file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

exports.registration = function(req,res){

    //Redirect the user if they are logged in 
    if(true !== req.session.loggedIn){

        res.render('register', { 

        });

    }else{

        res.redirect('/user');

    }
}
exports.doRegistration = function(req,res){

    //Redirect the user if they are logged in 
if(true !== req.session.loggedIn){

    User.create({

        fullName: req.body.register.fullName,
        email: req.body.register.email,
        password: req.body.register.password,
        createdOn: Date.now()

    }, function(err, user){

        if(err){

            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/register');

        }else{

            console.log('success');

            req.session.user = {

                "name": user.fullName,
                "email": user.email,
                "_id": user._id

            };

            req.session.loggedIn = true;
            res.redirect('/user');
        }

    });
}else{

           res.redirect('/user');

 }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, instead of repeating yourself for each route you could simply use some middleware to check if a user is logged in or not and add any logic there:

```
function ensureNewUser(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.loggedIn) {
        // if user is logged in redirect to /user
        res.redirect('/user');
    } else {
        // else next
        next();
    }
}
```

Then use that middleware in your route definitions:

```
app.get('/register', ensureNewUser, register.registration);
app.post('/register',ensureNewUser, register.doRegistration);
```

Not completely sure what you mean by "more secure way", hard to comment without knowing how you are handling authentication but  by "prevent them from making a POST request thought other means then a form" I assume you are talking about CSRF. In which case you should ensure you are using some CSRF middleware `app.use(express.csrf());` or if using `Express4` something like the [csurf](https://www.npmjs.org/package/csurf) module and then ensuring you are sending back the token in the request from your front end.